# Hide data from user Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

i have a need to save some data to LocalStorage that user must not modify - so i need to hide or encode it. How can i do this?

Lets say i wan't to store earned point count when i'm in offline mode, but when i'm back online i wan't to send data to server. But if user will modify the file then the data will be incorrect.

I have tried to use, but some namespaces don't exist in Windows 8:

```
public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
{
    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

    byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
    var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };
    var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));

    byte[] cipherTextBytes;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            cryptoStream.Close();
        }
        memoryStream.Close();
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific by "some namespaces doesnt exist"?
Also check if you have all needed includes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code works on standard .NET, but not on .NET for Windows Store apps.

It seems .NET for Windows Store Apps simply does not have `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged`.

The [`Windows.Security.Cryptography` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.aspx#classes) only has one class: `CryptographicBuffer`.

You'll have to use `SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm` to choose a symmetric encryption algorithm. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.openalgorithm%28v=win.10%29.aspx) you'll find a list of all the symmetric algorithms supported on WinRT.